# Update values from multiple columns into one using CONCAT display null value

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a table named contacts:

```
   ID  Address  Address2    Address3
    1    No 4     Jalan      Mawar
    2    No 1     Street 2   NULL
```

I had updated the values from these columns (Address, Address2, Address3) into:

```
       ID       combination
       1     No 4, Jalan, Mawar 
       2           NULL
```

by using this:

```
  update contacts set combination = concat(Address, ', ', Address2, ', ', Address3);
```

The problem is the updated value will be null if one the 3 columns is null.

Comment: See CONCAT_WS - assuming that's the outcome you want.

Comment: Sorry, did i have to replace CONCAT with CONCAT_WS in the command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alternatively you can use CONCAT_WS function. Detail information can be referred on W3Resource documentation [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat_ws-function.php).

```
update contacts set combination = CONCAT_WS (',', Address, Address2, Address3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query as below

`SELECT CONCAT_WS(',','1st string','2nd string', NULL);`

`update contacts set combination = CONCAT_WS(',',Address, Address2, Address3);`

Comment: Thanks, I already accept first answer, btw what is the purpose of this query SELECT CONCAT_WS(',','1st string','2nd string', NULL); ?

Comment: @MeShaa, that I have added for you to check if value is NULL it is giving correct answer